# Ansible command with mysql and stdin fails

Tags: mysql, ansible

I use the following command:

```
- name: Set client_secret
  command: >
    mysql
    -h {{ databases_map['auth']["db_host"] }}
    -P {{ databases_map['auth']["db_port"] }}
    -u {{ db_user }}
    -p
    -e "INSERT INTO APICredentials
    (`name`, `user_id`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `salt`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`)
    VALUES (
      'seeding',
      (SELECT id from User where type=1 AND username='{{ name }}'),
      'titi',
      'toto'),
      'salt',
      NOW(),
      NOW()
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    client_secret=('zzz'),
    salt='salt';"
  args:
    stdin: "{{ password }}"
```

Here the debug output shows that the command blocks on password prompt:

> 18518 1569401492.74748: stdout chunk (state=2):
>   >>>Enter password: <<<

If I set the password directly in the command:

```
-p{{ password }}
```

All work fine.

Do you have an idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt for the password in the beginning of the play.

```
vars_prompt:
    - name: password
      prompt: "What is your password?"
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html

Comment: I don't understand the link with your proposal and my issue. The password is store in inventory variable, I don't need to enter it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option with command module,

`stdin_add_newline: yes`

If set to yes, this option appends a newline to the stdin data.

It may be possible the command block is waiting for an endline, as we usually give an endline by pressing `Enter` key, when we install manually.

Supporting document : [Command Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module)

Comment: I didn't tell it but yes I tried this and same behavior

Comment: The option is added in Ansible 2.8, which version are you using?

Comment: The last one, 2.8.5, I tried too to downgrade to 2.7.12 to see if it's a 2.8 bug but no